# Is It Normal to See Warnings in the Availability Group Dashboard for an Empty SQL Server Availability Group?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I've recently set up a new SQL Server Availability Group using T-SQL scripts. The setup was slightly unconventional as I initiated the availability group without including any databases initially.

```
CREATE AVAILABILITY GROUP ag1
FOR
REPLICA ON 'node1'
    WITH (
        ENDPOINT_URL = N'TCP://node1.dev.com:5022',
        FAILOVER_MODE = MANUAL,
        AVAILABILITY_MODE = ASYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT,
        BACKUP_PRIORITY = 50,
        SECONDARY_ROLE (ALLOW_CONNECTIONS = ALL),
        SEEDING_MODE = MANUAL
    ),
    N'node2'
    WITH (
        ENDPOINT_URL = N'TCP://node2.dev.com:5022',
        FAILOVER_MODE = MANUAL,
        AVAILABILITY_MODE = ASYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT,
        BACKUP_PRIORITY = 50,
        SECONDARY_ROLE (ALLOW_CONNECTIONS = ALL),
        SEEDING_MODE = MANUAL
    );
```

After setting up the primary replica, I added a secondary replica and configured a listener for the group. All the T-SQL commands executed successfully without any errors.

However, upon inspecting the SQL Server Availability Group dashboard, I noticed there are some warnings displayed. Here's a snapshot of what the dashboard looks like:

[image]

Given that the Availability Group is currently empty (no databases have been added yet), I'm wondering if these warnings are typical in such a scenario or if they indicate a potential configuration issue that I should address.

Has anyone experienced a similar situation with empty Availability Groups, or does anyone know if these warnings are simply standard placeholders until databases are added?

Any insights or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Given that the Availability Group is currently empty (no databases have been added yet), I'm wondering if these warnings are typical in such a scenario or if they indicate a potential configuration issue that I should address.

This is expected. It's all backed by Policy Based Management checks and those aren't really smart enough the way they are currently written to notice that there are no databases which is considered "ok".

You're good, nothing wrong.

Comment: Thank you again Sir! Happy valentine's day!